# TextView multiline clipping in TableRow

Tags: android

I have searched for couple of hours about this problem, but found no helping solution.
Here is the problem

[image]

The textview at [0, 0] got clipped when using multiline. And here is xml code.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testtextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="Line 1\nLine2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

I've tried adding padding and margin, but nothing seems to be working, what could be the problem ? Thanks :)

PS : Doesn't happen in Android 1.6 and I also tried setting text programmatically, even with `HTML.fromHtml` using `<br/>`, seems like bad measuring of View.

Edit:
Wow adding BottomMargin works now, It didn't work last time, really sometimes Eclipse doesn't builds and uploads last built version. Quite annoying, specially when testing something like this.

Comment: Have you tried just two TextViews and see how that lays out? You can always go back and fine tune it. Not sure if you have tried adding padding to the top of the objects below the TextView. Such as the "Some Text Here".

Comment: I just did a test, I increased the height of the Spinner(right side of TV) and TV wasn't clipped anymore. So the problem seems to be with TableRow measurement, maybe its just taking last column as max Row height, like GridView, which is quite bad.

Comment: Good work and Good job for solving it on your own!